# How do I confirm that one string sequence is a subset of another?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I don't know how to determine whether one set of strings (xs:string*) is a subset of a reference set of strings.

I assumed that node-set operations would work with xs:string*, but they work with type node(), not xs:string. I tried the simpler contains() function as well, which only works on single strings, not sequences of strings.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="permitted" select="tokenize('1,2,3,278', ',')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>

<xsl:template match="experience">
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="tokenize(ids, ', ')"/>

<xsl:if test="count($permitted | $test)=count($permitted)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this:

Error: Required item type of document-order sorter is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise about the requirement. Is (a, b) a subset of (a, b, c)? What about (a, c) or (a, a, b) or (c, b, a)? It's a little confusing that you talk about sequences and subsets rather than sequences/subsequences or sets/subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
not($vTest[not(. = $vPermitted)])
```

**XSLT- based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPermitted" as="xs:string*" select="'1', '2', '3', '278'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vTest1" as="xs:string*" select="'1', '2', '3'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vTest2" as="xs:string*" select="'1', '2', '3', '4'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="not($vTest1[not(. = $vPermitted)])"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="not($vTest2[not(. = $vPermitted)])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (not used) the two XPath expressions are evaluated and their correct, wanted results are output**:

```
true false
```

**Note**:

Exactly the same expression can be used even in XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0), where there is no concept of a sequence, but one can use node-sets instead.

---

**Explanation**:

This is the "**[Principle of Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**". This principle is considered to be a law of thought in classical logic. The principle was stated as a theorem of propositional logic by Russell and Whitehead in Principia Mathematica as:

[image]

"This is the principle of double negation, i.e. a proposition is equivalent of the falsehood of its negation."

---

**Most optimal implementation -- close to `O(N)`**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPermitted" as="map(xs:string, xs:boolean)" select=
    "map{'1' : true(), '2' : true(), '3' : true(), '278' : true()}"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vTest1" as="xs:string*" select="'1', '2', '3'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vTest2" as="xs:string*" select="'1', '2', '3', '4'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="not($vTest1[not($vPermitted(.))])"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="not($vTest2[not($vPermitted(.))])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (not used) the two XPath expressions are evaluated and their correct, wanted results are output**:

```
true false
```

While the previous expressions (including the ones in the currently accepted answer) all have time complexity `O(M*N)`, the above **[XPath 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/)** expression uses a pre-populated (global / created only once) **[map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps)** so that any check if a key exists takes constant time -- **thus the total time complexity of this algorithm is `O(N)`**

Here we make the reasonable assumption that the XPath engine in use has a well-optimized map implementation, such as one that is based on hash-tables

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. This is certainly less obvious syntactically than what @Martin Honnen suggested. Are there performance advantages?

Comment: @MatthewFarabaugh: As pointed out, this is more general -- it can be used in XPath 1.0 too. Also, this is one of the most general laws of Logic -- and is both fundamental and obvious -- any statement is the negation of its negation. Javascript programmers use this as a common code pattern of converting any value to a boolean by double-negating it: `!!x`   And it is certainly more that twice as short/er than both expressions provided in the accepted answer. Many people will enjoy this solution as I truly do :)

Comment: @MatthewFarabaugh As for performance advantages, I think that all 3 proposed expressions have the same time complexity: O(M*N) because all possible pairs of items from the two sets need to be considered for (in)equality. An O(N) solution is possible if an XPath 3.1 Map is constructed in advance (globally / once), because checking if an item is a key in a map should take close to constant time.

Comment: @MatthewFarabaugh I updated the answer -- look at the very end -- and it now includes probably the fastest  solution with only O(N) time complexity -- using Maps. Still based on the fundamental law of Logic ... :) Enjoy!

Comment: This is a lot of excellent information. Thank you. Suppose I wanted to implement a map solution on a string parameter passed into the stylesheet. I would presumably break it up with tokenize(). How would I make a map of this sort from it? Or is there a way to pass a map into a stylesheet? Please let me know if this is better left to a separate question thread. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewFarabaugh, Yes, one can pass a string parameter to the transformation, then get a sequence of its substrings and create a map from this. If you ask this as a separate question, please notify me via a comment. Is my answer more or less useful than the currently-aceppted one?

Comment: Adding a note because another recent question refers to this post. Note that the time complexity depends on the algorithm used, and the algorithm depends on the optimizer. For example a naive implementation of X=Y involves count(X)*count(Y) comparisons, but (a) this is worst case because it can exit as soon as it finds a match, and (b) a more sophisticated implementation will use a hash table.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for this comment. Yes, the exit will be "as soon as it finds a match" and statistically (on average) this will require `count(X)*count(Y) div 2` comparisons, but multiplying an `O(someExpression)` by a constant (`0.5`)  gives us still `O(someExpression)` .  As for having faith in the optimizer, well, this has all the drawbacks of having faith blindly and in general. A better step forward from having faith in `something` is to verify this `something` is true. This is why in this answer I am offering the explicit use of maps (yes, maps are only available in XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you use (XPath 2 and later) `every $s in $test satisfies $s = $permitted` then I think your check should work for sequences of atomic values like strings.

As an alternative: `count($test) = count($test[. = $permitted])`

Comment: I found some information on "quantified expressions" like these. I will look into them now. Thank you.

Comment: Martin and @MatthewFarabaugh: Both of these expressions have `O(M*N)` time complexity. There exists a solution only of `O(N)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Set operations do not work on strings, but sequence operations do. Your attempt:

```
<xsl:if test="count($permitted | $test)=count($permitted)">
```

could be rewritten as:

```
<xsl:if test="deep-equal(distinct-values(($permitted, $test)), $permitted)">
```

Comment: The statement "Set operations do not work on strings, but sequence operations do" needs clarification -- it is true for **node-sets** -- not for any sets. It is possible to implement a set of strings -- yes, real set where there is no order -- with XPath 3.1 maps. This solution can be also the fastest -- O(N) vs. O(M*N)