# How do I only output a record if and only if all the values are the desired ones using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a large XML file with many request, within each request there may be multiple orders. I want to only output the request if all its orders have a certain status that indicate its been completed.

The Status `<Stat>` I want are Stat03, Stat04, Stat05 and Stat06.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <BO>
        <MainReq>
            <UR>
                <ReqNum>REQ001.00</ReqNum>
                <Description>Description 01</Description>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.01</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat05</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.02</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat04</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.03</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat06</Stat>
                </PH>
            </UR>
        </MainReq>
        <MainReq>
            <UR>
                <ReqNum>REQ002.00</ReqNum>
                <Description>Description 02</Description>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.01</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat05</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.02</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat04</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.03</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat03</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.04</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat06</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.05</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat01</Stat>
                </PH>
            </UR>
        </MainReq>
    </BO>
</document>
```

`<MainReq>` contains the request and within it there can be multiple orders `<PH>`

The desire output would be this, since the only request that meets the criteria is REQ001.
REQ002 has one `<PH>` that is in Stat01 so it does not qualify.

```
<document>
   <BO>
      <IfReq>
         <ReqNum>REQ001</ReqNum>
         <Date>2022-07-21+02:00</Date>
      </IfReq>
   </BO>
</document>
```

My solution was to count all the `<PH>` and then count ONLY the `<Stat>` that are in any of the these states, Stat03, Stat04, Stat05 and Stat06. Once I have those values I can compare them and if they are equal I output the request number and date. A `<MainReq>` does not have to have all of those states but I only want to count the `<PH>` that are in that set of states to compare with the total count of `<PH>`.

Edit to add more clarity..

My XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
        xmlns:lookup="lookup" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="xml/plain" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="MainReq">
      
      <xsl:variable name="subTotalCount">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(UR/PH/PN)" />
      </xsl:variable>
      
      <xsl:variable name="subCompletedCount">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="UR/PH/Stat = 'Stat03' and 'Stat04' and 'Stat05' and 'Stat06'">
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(count(UR/PH/Stat) )" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      
      <!-- This is the final output -->
      <xsl:if test= "$subTotalCount = $subCompletedCount">
        <IfReq>
          <xsl:copy-of select="UR/ReqNum"/>
          <Date>
          <xsl:value-of  select="current-date()"/>
        </Date>
        </IfReq>
      </xsl:if>
      
      <!--  For debugging  -->
      
      <Req>
        <xsl:copy-of select="UR/ReqNum"/>
      </Req>
      <sub>
        <TotalCount>
          <xsl:value-of select="$subTotalCount"/>
        </TotalCount>
        <compCount>
          <xsl:value-of select="$subCompletedCount"/>
        </compCount>
        <xsl:copy-of select="UR/PH/PN"/>
      </sub>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is "The Status `<Stat>` I want are Stat03, Stat04, Stat05 and Stat06" supposed to say "The Status `<Stat>` I want are Stat03, Stat04, Stat05 or Stat06"? I don't see all those values in the request you say you want to select/output so it rather seems you only want to check that each `PH` has the `Stat` equal to one of those four values. The most expressive description in XPath 2.0 would be e.g. to select/match `MainReq[every $order in UR/PH satisfies $order/Stat = ('Stat03', 'Stat04', 'Stat05', 'Stat06')]`.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58788328/3016153

Comment: @Martin Honnen The request can have any number or orders '<PH>' so as long as all the PH/Stat is in one of the statuses needed Stat03, Stat04, Stat05 and Stat06 it qualifies to be counted. Example: if a request has two '<PH>' and one is in '<Stat>Stat02</Stat>' and the other is '<Stat>Stat05</Stat>', that does not qualify. Stat02 is not a status I want to count. However if another request also has two '<PH>' that are in '<Stat>Stat04</Stat>' and '<Stat>Stat06</Stat>', Yes this qualify because Stat04 and Stat06 are ones I the set I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
<!-- This is the final output -->
<xsl:if test="count(UR/PH/Stat) = count(UR/PH/Stat[matches(. , 'Stat0[3456]')])">
  <IfReq>
    <xsl:copy-of select="UR/ReqNum"/>
    <Date>
      <xsl:value-of  select="current-date()"/>
    </Date>
  </IfReq>
</xsl:if>
```

It uses `count` on `matches()` in the predicate to count the wanted Stat and compares is with total `count` of Stat

Comment: This may* work for the given example, but would be very difficult, if not impossible to adapt to a more general solution where the list of permitted values might not fit into a pattern. --- (*) In fact, as written it will fail with a value like `Stat031`.

Comment: @Siebe Jongebloed. This worked perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: As @michael.hor257k pointed out, it will fail for anything that does not match that pattern. Fortunately for me, I only have those 6 possible values so I can get away with this solution.

Comment: @noobSlayer If you only have 6 possible values, and 4 of those are permitted, it might be much easier (and possibly more efficient too) to look for the presence of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a bit difficult to follow, but I think you are asking for

```
//MainReq[every $s in .//Stat satisfies $s = ('Stat03', 'Stat04', 'Stat05', 'Stat06')]
```

Comment: Isn't `.//Stat != ('Stat03', 'Stat04', 'Stat05', 'Stat06')` always true?

Comment: Fixed by removing it (as correcting it is too complicated).

Comment: The "corrected" version can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792165/3016153

Answer (score 1):

**Use this one-liner XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
//MainReq[not(.//Stat[not(. = ('Stat03', 'Stat04', 'Stat05', 'Stat06'))])]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//MainReq[not(.//Stat[not(. = ('Stat03', 'Stat04', 'Stat05', 'Stat06'))])]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <BO>
        <MainReq>
            <UR>
                <ReqNum>REQ001.00</ReqNum>
                <Description>Description 01</Description>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.01</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat05</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.02</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat04</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ001.03</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat06</Stat>
                </PH>
            </UR>
        </MainReq>
        <MainReq>
            <UR>
                <ReqNum>REQ002.00</ReqNum>
                <Description>Description 02</Description>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.01</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat05</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.02</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat04</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.03</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat03</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.04</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat06</Stat>
                </PH>
                <PH>
                    <PN>REQ002.05</PN>
                    <Stat>Stat01</Stat>
                </PH>
            </UR>
        </MainReq>
    </BO>
</document>
```

**The Xpath expression is evaluated, and the result of this evaluation (all selected nodes) is sent to the output**:

```
<MainReq>
    <UR>
        <ReqNum>REQ001.00</ReqNum>
        <Description>Description 01</Description>
        <PH>
            <PN>REQ001.01</PN>
            <Stat>Stat05</Stat>
        </PH>
        <PH>
            <PN>REQ001.02</PN>
            <Stat>Stat04</Stat>
        </PH>
        <PH>
            <PN>REQ001.03</PN>
            <Stat>Stat06</Stat>
        </PH>
    </UR>
</MainReq>
```

**Explanation**:

For a full explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792165/36305